# Advice for State Management on an Individual Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, state-management

I've got a problem that may either be a limitation in my approach or asp.net web forms technology. The main driver for this solution is the simple fact that when users sit on an individual page for an extended period of time, they are redirected to our CAS server and back to the page itself which results in all of the form inputs being cleared as if the user did not enter any information (i.e. losing the ViewState/control state). With that being said I was exploring other options such as:

- Using HTML localStorage to store a JSON string of all values on the page that can be parsed into an object and loaded into the form later if needed.

Even though this solution allowed me to store values on each page in individual key/value pairs (page instance 1 in localStorage[ID1], page instance 2 in localStorage[ID2] etc.), there was still a limitation on the server side of validating which page the user is saving. Right now I am using the session to maintain which form the user is viewing ie. the user is only associated with 1 page. To continue the example, the session information would result in the user being associated with either localStorage[ID1] or localStorage[ID2], not both ---which is precisely my problem. I need to communicate from the client-side which one page is to be saved. I've explored the following options, and come up with the following questions:

1. A static class that contains a static collection of objects on the server side storing which users have which pages open--> problem: communicating which page is actually being saved.
2. Dynamically rendering my save buttons with IDs that include an encrypted version of the page identifier at hand.
3. Storing the current value being edited in the Querystring
4. A cookie value that stores the value of the ID that the user wishes to change on post back-->how will the cookie get its value--especially when an ID is new (user is filling out form for the first time)?

I may be over complicating this and I know there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites solve this problem by displaying a dialog when the user has sat on the page too long, asking if they still want to maintain their session. If the user doesn't click "Yes", then lose the session.

Another solution would be to permit a user who *knows* he's going to not use the page for a while to save the results so far and to restore them later, and continue.

Before proceeding with a technological solution, I'd try to find out *why* the users are sitting on the page so long. Whatever their reason is, you'll want to try to accommodate it if it's a good reason.

If the reason is "because we don't really care about your page and just didn't bother to close it", then your current solution works fine.

Comment: If I decide to go the dialog route, asking the user to keep their own session alive--how could I differentiate between individual sessions (different instances of the same page opened in different tabs) on the server side? I will store a basic object per user per page instance in the session. I think the krux of the issue is how to properly identify the session and then have the client relay to the server that identifiable information. Are cookies reliable enough? I don't think the viewstate is robust enough given the CAS redirection issues described above.

Comment: If you need different tabs to be different "sessions" then you'll need to do that yourself. The tabs would have the same value for the session state cookie. Maybe just add hidden field of your own in each page.

Comment: I am not sure if the CAS redirection would cause the hidden field to lose its value (similar to the rest of the form as described above).

Comment: After some consideration I believe storing encrypted values in the query-string will satisfy my goal of keeping multiple instances of the same page open at the same time. On the other hand, if only one instance of the same page is allowed per user, storing key information in the session with a timeout notification as described above will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to close out my own issue. I will resolve my problem by storing encrypted values in the query string to maintain page state. From there I will all values the user enters on the page within stringified json objects within localStorage. For example: page 1 with id: aa will have one key value pair within localStorage in the format [appName_pageId]. Page 2 with id bb will have a similar key value pair. If the user gets redirected to our CAS server and lands back on my page with all values cleared, I will be able to load the correct inputs from localStorage based on the value in the query string parameter (aa or bb). The important principle to remember here is that central control belongs on the server and distributed control should be done on the client.